# Continuity and Differentiability of $h(x) = min(f(x), g(x)) $, where $f(x) = x(1 − x)$ and $g(x) = x/2$

Tags: derivatives

> Let $f$, $g$ and $h$  be real valued functions defined as follows:
>   $f(x) = x(1 − x)$,   $g(x) = x/2$  and  $h(x) = min(f(x), g(x)) $ 
>   with $0<x<1$  Then $h$ is:
>
> A) continuous and differentiable
>
> B) is differentiable but not continuous
>
> C) is continuous but not differentiable
>
> D) is neither continuous nor differentiable

How to go about this? 
$ h(x)= \begin{cases}
g(x) & \text{ if } 0<x<0.5 \\ 
 f(x)& \text{ if } 0.5<x<1
\end{cases}$
is this correct?

Comment: Did you try plotting the function? Do you think it is continuous? Do you think it is differentiable? By the way, what you wrote is indeed correct.

Comment: In these type of questions, always try to draw the graphs of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and then shade the part of the graphs which is lesser, this will give you the graph oh $h(x)$. For differentiability, you can then see the corner points.

Answer (score 2):

From the graph we can clearly see that $h(x)$ is continuous everywhere but not differentiable at $x=0.5$

[image]

Comment: Note to OP: "Seeing from a graph" is not a valid method for solving mathematical problems. It's useful to see the solution, but the solution must then still be *proven*.